# Making sense of Azure Devops Repo Git Graph

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using Azure Devops repos for the first time and I'm tying to make sense of the graph of commits. I'm working off a Dev branch and a Main branch. At first it seemed like the dev branch was blue and and on the left, and the main branch was gray and to the right.

However with my last merge it unexpectedly merged to the left, so apparently I'm wrong about left and right. I also noticed the initial creation of the repository was blue, so I'm wrong about blue meaning dev branch.

What do the blue and gray dots mean, and what is the difference between left and right on the graph?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6rNL.png]

Answer (score 1):

- Blue dots are commits.
- Gray dots are merges.
- Left is one branch, and right is another branch. If you had yet another branch, it would appear side-by-side. Usually, the left-most branch is the main/master branch, and derived branches are expanded to the right.

Source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/announcing-git-graph-and-advanced-filters-to-visualize-commit-history/